# convert a 32-byte hex string into a 16-byte string of hex values

Tags: java, hex

I'm trying to convert a 32-byte string of hex characters (b8aa30d8f1d398883f0eeb5079777c42) into a 16-byte string of hex values (x'b8aa30d8f1d398883f0eeb5079777c42')

I've tried some of the suggestions I've found here.

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        String s = input.substring(i, i + 2);       
        byte value = Byte.valueOf(s, 16);
                       sb.append(value);
    }
```

this resulted in this Exception: Value out of range. Value:"b8" Radix:16

```
         String bin = "";
    String binFragment = "";
    int iHex;
    hex = hex.trim();
    hex = hex.replaceFirst("0x", "");

    for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){
        iHex = Integer.parseInt(""+hex.charAt(i),16);
        binFragment = Integer.toBinaryString(iHex);

        while(binFragment.length() < 4){
            binFragment = "0" + binFragment;
        }
        bin += binFragment;
    }
```

this doesn't handle leading 0's correctly

does anyone have a way to do this conversion?

I also tried this:

```
public static void convert() {
    String s = "0c871eea3af7526f9b2e7054f6277984";
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    StringBuilder outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte currentByte : bytes) {
        outputStringBuilder.append((char) currentByte);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s", bytes, bytes.length));
    String out = bytes.toString();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s", out, out.length()));
}
```

and got these results:
[B@f01a1e, 16
[B@f01a1e, 9

There are 16 bytes in the byte array before creating the output string, but only 9 after.

Comment: "byte string of hex values."  This makes no sense.

Comment: pleases post more examples of input and output also byte is signed so b8 is too big to fit in a byte

Comment: `Integer.toBinaryString()` will convert the integer to a String of zeroes and ones which are the binary representation of that integer. Is that what you really want? You wouldn't get a 16-byte string, you'd get a 128 bytes string of zeroes and ones. Perhaps you want to convert the 32 byte hex string to an array of bytes? That would give you a binary array of 16 bytes.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer is you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: The title is confusing.  What you really mean to ask is "how do I convert a number from a 32 character hexadecimal string into a 16 element byte[] array?"  For this purpose, I think you should probably use the ByteBuffer class which is part of the java.nio library.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think he/she meant grouping hex characters in pairs, representing them as bytes rather than single-characters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to convert a sequence of bytes (given in hexadecimal notation as a String) to the corresponding characters.

You can use the [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class to convert the hex-string into an array of bytes ...

```
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(inputString);
```

... and convert each byte to the character it represents:

```
StringBuilder outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (byte currentByte : bytes) {
    outputStringBuilder.append((char) currentByte);
}
```

Comment: This produces garbage (`ﾸﾪ0￘￱ￓﾘﾈ?￫Pyw|B`) for your input, though, so I'm not sure if you might be trying to achieve something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem with your second attempt is that you read two hex characters at a time (which is correct, since each pair of hex characters is a single byte), but your loop condition and increment are wrong.

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length()/2; i+=2) {
    String s = input.substring(i, i + 2);       
    byte value = Byte.valueOf(s, 16);
                   sb.append(value);
}
```

In addition you should also check that the input has an even number of hex characters.